# Maximum Allometry of aquatic mammals omitting Kleiber's Law

Tags: physiology, metabolism, marine-biology, allometry

As far as I understand, blue whales cannot get any physically larger due to the extremely demanding caloric intake it has on consuming large quantities of krill, not due to any other physiological reasons, as it for what limits a land animals's, being their bones not being able to support their own weight.
Be that the case, how big can an aquatic mammal be, in terms of volume and/or mass?
Would other organism's, such as Hydrozoa, to name one example, display any difference in this regard?

For reference on the Blue Whale size being limited by caloric consumption, here is a link on a study:

https://science.sciencemag.org/content/366/6471/1367.abstract

Goldbogen, J. A., et al. "Why whales are big but not bigger: Physiological drivers and ecological limits in the age of ocean giants." Science 366.6471 (2019): 1367-1372.
APA

Comment: Welcome to the site! "As far as I understand" is really insufficient... please source your claim, and demonstrate what research you have done so far.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I will post a link to what I am referencing about. 
I am not studying biology as my main career, that being Material Science, but I have always have had a fascination with marine biology, so pardon if sometimes my knowledge isn’t up to standard.